# Escaping strings from AppleScript for sqlite3

Tags: sqlite, applescript

I want to collect some data from e-mail messages in Mac Mail, using AppleScript, then write this data into a sqlite3 database using "do shell script". The problem is, one of the things I want to write is data from the message body, which can contain all manner of special characters that could choke the process of passing the data to sqlite3.

What's the best way of escaping this data? Or is there a better way to do this than using "do shell script" within AppleScript?

Answer (score 0):

Without example problematic data I'm assuming quoting is the only issue where as fully binary safe would require more code.

```
on sqlite_quote(subject)
    set OLD_TID to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    try
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "\\'"
        set subject to subject's quoted form's text items
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
        set subject to subject as string

        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to OLD_TID
    on error error_message number error_number from error_source partial result error_result to error_class
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to OLD_TID

        error error_message number error_number from error_source partial result error_result to error_class
    end try

    subject
end sqlite_quote
on sqlite_quotes(subjects)
    set subjects to {} & subjects
    repeat with subject in subjects
        set subject's contents to sqlite_quote(subject)
    end repeat
    subjects
end sqlite_quotes
on sqlite_fields_quote(sources)
    my list2string(",", sqlite_quotes(sources))
end sqlite_fields_quote

on sqlite_stmnt_create_table_ifnexists(table, columns)
    "create table if not exists " & sqlite_quote(table) & "(" & sqlite_fields_quote(columns) & ")"
end sqlite_stmnt_create_table_ifnexists
on sqlite_stmnt_drop_table_ifexists(table)
    "drop table if exists " & sqlite_quote(table)
end sqlite_stmnt_drop_table_ifexists
on sqlite_stmnt_insert_into(table, values)
    "insert into " & sqlite_quote(table) & " values(" & sqlite_fields_quote(values) & ")"
end sqlite_stmnt_insert_into


on list2string(delimiter, source) -- general utility
    try
        set {|applescript's text item delimiters|, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, delimiter}
        set |result| to source as string
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to |applescript's text item delimiters|
    on error error_message number error_number from error_source partial result error_result to error_class
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to |applescript's text item delimiters|
        error error_message number error_number from error_source partial result error_result to error_class
    end try
    |result|
end list2string


property executable : "sqlite3"
property db_path : "/tmp/test.sqlite"

on run argv
    set {table, values} to {"table", {"example with CRLF: " & («data TEXT0D0A» as text) & " using applescript's TIDs on this string's quoted form"}} -- example

    set {stmnts, test_ins, test_drp, debug} to {{}, true, false, false}

    if test_drp then set stmnts's end to sqlite_stmnt_drop_table_ifexists(table)
    if test_ins then set stmnts's end to sqlite_stmnt_create_table_ifnexists(table, "text")

    set stmnts's end to sqlite_stmnt_insert_into(table, values)

    if test_ins then set stmnts's end to "select * from " & sqlite_quote(table)

    set |script| to executable & space & db_path's quoted form & space & my list2string(";", stmnts)'s quoted form

    if debug then set |script| to "echo >&2 " & |script|'s quoted form & ";" & |script| & "|xxd"

    do shell script |script|
end run
```